# Where can I publish a 50 fps video?

Tags: video, software, recommendation

I've produced a video in 50 fps progressive. I am having a hard time getting anyone to actually see it: all popular online video players are artificially capped to 30 fps.

Is there any way I can publish this video without halving the framerate to 25 fps, which looks atrocious due to the fast shutter used?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that [dailymotion.com](http://www.dailymotion.com/us) can have 50 fps videos, though the recommended is 25 fps. [Here](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x92u89_derelict-bmx-march-in-50-frames-per_music?search_algo=1) is an upload that ***says*** that it is in 50fps.
I am not completely sure, so you might have to just end up converting it to 25.

Comment: It looks like it's 25fps. The video was shot in 50fps and then slowed to 25fps.

Comment: Well @romkyns, the only place I could find to upload 50fps videos online is [pinkbike](http://www.pinkbike.com/), a Mountain Biking site (heh). It specifically says [here](http://www.pinkbike.com/news/Frames-per-second-50-vs-25p-2010.html) that it can. Not that you would want to do that....